# Socket.IO & SSL

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, socket.io

i activated HTTPS and Socket.IO returned error:

> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Server.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(‘./cert.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(‘./cert.crt')
};

var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = https.createServer(options, app);
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
    server.listen(8080);
```

Front:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>

var socket = io.connect('IP:8080');
```

If deactivated HTTPS, Socket.IO worked...

Answer (score 0):

two theories:

1) Are you hosting this remotely? If so, you may not have the same port number as your local server. For instance, on Heroku hosted node apps, you can access the port number with:

```
process.env.PORT
```

So you could do:

```
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

2) It may also be a CORS issue. You will need to include access-control-allow-origin headers. Include a middleware utility like the following between setting up 'app' and calling 'server.listen(...)':

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type');

    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end();
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps